# Adding a classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following code which runs correctly:

```
import math

class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
         yield self.x
         yield self.y

    def __add__(self, other):
        addedx = self.x + other.x
        addedy = self.y + other.y
        return Point(addedx, addedy)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        mulx = self.x * other
        muly = self.y * other
        return Point(mulx, muly)

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(


    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)


    def distance(self, self2):
         return math.sqrt((self2.x - self.x) ** 2 + (self2.y - self.y) ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

I want to add a @classmethod called from_tuple to the Point class that allows creation of Point instances from a tuple containing the x and y values. I want to make it so the tuple input is required. I am lost on the syntax of how to do something like this. The following is the expected output:

```
location = 2, 3
print(location)
    (2, 3)
point = Point.from_tuple(location)
print(point)
    Point(x=2, y=3)
point = Point.from_tuple()
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: from_tuple() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coords'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `classmethod` is very similar to an instance method, except that:

- You can call it on the class itself without getting an "unbound method" that needs an extra argument, and
- Whether you call it on the class itself or on an instance, you get the class object as your first parameter.

Traditionally, you name that parameter `cls`. So:

```
@classmethod
def from_tuple(cls, tup):
    x, y = tup
    return cls(x, y)
```

---

You may be wondering why you need `cls` at all here. After all, couldn't you just write this as a `staticmethod`?

```
@staticmethod
def from_tuple(tup):
    x, y = tup
    return Point(x, y)
```

Yes, you can—but that doesn't play nice with inheritance. If I make a subclass of `Point`, and call `MyPoint.from_tuple(2, 3)`, I'd expect to get a `MyPoint` back, not a `Point`. By using a `classmethod` and constructing an instance of `cls` instead of hardcoding `Point`, I get a `MyPoint`, because `cls` is `MyPoint`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just a follow up question, how would one create a method that allows updating the x, y values of a Point instance from a tuple. I want to do this such that if  point = Point(3, 4) and i say for example point.loc_tuple((5, 6)) the output would be  Point(x=5, y=6).

Comment: @user10200421 You want to modify it in-place? Then just write a method that does that: `def loc_tuple(self, tup): self.x, self.y = tup`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just

```
@classmethod
def from_tuple(cls, location):
    return cls(*location)
```